# Selenium scrapping data while loading elements [Python]

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Is there any way to sequentially scrape only the newly generated items?
I have some sort of dynamic list that loads by scroll.
As I see it now, I can scrape all generated divs in 2 ways:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the list and afterwards scrape all generated divs.
2. Scroll once, scrape generated divs. Scroll again, scrape the newly generated ones and so on until I reach the end.

I believe that the 2nd method is more efficient, but I don't know how to put it in practice.

If I go

```
> scroll

> all_div = list_ul.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '')
```

The all_div will always contain all ( not only the newly ) generated divs. So if I get 5 new divs/scroll, the previously loaded divs will appear in any further all_div call.
Something like:

```
all_div call ->> return 5 elements



scroll ->>generated 5 new divs

all_div call ->> return 10 elements 

scroll ->>generated 5 new divs

all_div call ->> return 15 elements 

scroll ->>generated 5 new divs
```

... and so on.

And this will probably be even less efficient than the 1) method, as it will eventually scrape all the generated divs after getting to the bottom of the list, but it will also scrape the partially loaded list.

I want it to go something like this, if possible:

```
all_div call ->> return 5 initial elements , append them to element_list

scroll ->>generated 5 new divs 

all_div call ->> return only the 5 newly generated elements, append them to element_list
scroll ->>generated 5 more new divs 

all_div call ->> return only the 5 newly generated elements, append them to element_list
```

... and so on.

In a loop, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach one would be better and efficient but if you still want to got with Approach #2 then you can try below

```
# get all initial elements
all_divs = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '')

# create a shallow copy of to avoid modifying the original list
element_list = all_divs[:] 

# set the initial count of scraped elements
count = len(all_divs)


while True: 
    # scroll to the bottom of the page and load more elements
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") 

    # wait for new elements to load, you can increase this or add a dynamic wait which would be better as per your need
    time.sleep(5) 

    # get only the new elements that were not in the initial list by using the count variable to slice the list
    new_divs = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '')[count:] 

    # append the new scraped elements to the list
    element_list.extend(new_divs) 

    # update the count of  elements
    count += len(new_divs) 

    # check if no new elements were found and then break out of loop
    if len(new_divs) == 0:
        break

# print the total number of elements and their text
print(len(element_list))
for e in element_list:
    print(e.text)

# quit the driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Indeed it seems that approach 2 is over complicating the situation. I thought there was some pre-built function for it.